# C# XML LINQ Syntax on Attributes

Tags: xml, linq

Can someone help me with the correct LINQ syntax to extract the statuses out of this XML?

Ideally, i would like to have the following printed out:

statuses: Open=1

statuses: Pending=2

statuses: Ignored=3

statuses: Closed=4

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <scope name="com">
    <scope name="company">
        <scope name="app">
        <scope name="app_monitor">
            <scope name="statuses">
            <entry name="Open">1</entry>
            <entry name="Pending">2</entry>
            <entry name="Ignored">3</entry>
            <entry name="Closed">4</entry>
            </scope>
            <scope name="urgencies">
            <entry name="Critical">1</entry>
            <entry name="Alarm">2</entry>
            <entry name="Info">3</entry>
            </scope>                       
        </scope>
        </scope>
    </scope>
    </scope>
</configuration>
```

I tried different variations of things, but here is how far I got:

```
    XDocument Xdocument = new XDocument();
    var doc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\temp\app_sett.xml");
    var returnedvalues = from app_sett in doc.Descendants("scope")
                where app_sett.Attribute("name").Value == "statuses"
                select new                                  
                {
                   blah = app_sett.Attribute("name").Value,
                };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to get the child elements of the relevant scope element. For example:

```
var query = doc.Descendants("scope")
               .Where(x => (string) x.Attribute("name") == "statuses")
               .Elements("entry")
               .Select(entry => new { Name = (string) entry.Attribute("name"),
                                      Value = (int) entry });
```